# Pass Dynamic Column name with dynamic asc or desc in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

How can we pass dynamic column names with dynamic `ASC` or `DESC` in a select statement as in the following case:

```
SELECT emp_name, emp_id 
FROM employee 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN :p_asc='asc' THEN :p_column_name END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN :p_asc='asc' THEN :p_column_name END) DESC;
```

This query is not working - column names are not accepted - please help to achieve this.

Comment: You can't unless use **dynamic SQL** . Btw, the brackets and the **ASC** at the end of the penultimate line are redundant.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan You can if you list the columns in the `WHEN` clause with corresponding values in the `THEN` clause and add `ELSE`. Also, the `ASC` is relevant from a code-review perspective as it explicitly states to the reviewer what the behaviour is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on tool you use. SQL*Plus lets you do that. Here's example:

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> accept p_col prompt "Enter column name for sorting purposes: "
Enter column name for sorting purposes: ename
SQL> accept p_asc_desc prompt "Asc or Desc? "
Asc or Desc? desc
SQL>
SQL> select ename from emp order by &p_col &p_asc_desc;

ENAME
----------
WARD
TURNER
SMITH
SCOTT
MILLER
MARTIN
KING
JONES
JAMES
FORD
CLARK
BLAKE
ALLEN
ADAMS

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Right; rows are sorted by `ENAME` column in `DESC`ending order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whitelist the column names in the `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` expression and put the column value into the `THEN` clause (otherwise you are sorting on the value of the bind variable and not the value of the column); and then
2. Use an `ELSE` clause and a static value so that when the condition is not matched then that part of the `ORDER BY` clause will give all the rows the same priority and you can specify the `ORDER` in a later part of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT emp_name, emp_id 
FROM   employee 
ORDER BY
       CASE 
       WHEN :p_column_name = 'EMP_NAME' AND :p_asc='asc'
       THEN emp_name
       WHEN :p_column_name = 'EMP_ID' AND :p_asc='asc'
       THEN TO_CHAR(emp_id, '000000') -- Assuming it is a number
       ELSE 'All rows ordered identically'
       END ASC,
       CASE 
       WHEN :p_column_name = 'EMP_NAME' AND :p_asc='desc'
       THEN emp_name
       WHEN :p_column_name = 'EMP_ID' AND :p_asc='desc'
       THEN TO_CHAR(emp_id, '000000') -- Assuming it is a number
       ELSE 'All rows ordered identically'
       END DESC;
```

Alternatively, build your query using dynamic SQL (ensuring that you sanitise your inputs to prevent SQL injection).